# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError when trying to run airflow webserver. Says no 'role' named 'ubuntu'

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm trying to run the airflow server using the command `airflow webserver`. but I ran into `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError when trying to run airflow webserver. Says no 'role' named 'ubuntu'`. I'm using postgresql I ran the following commands:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo airflow 
#to create new user airflow

su - airflow
#switched to airflow

sudo -u postgres psql
#launched postgresql shell

CREATE USER airflow PASSWORD ‘myPassword’;
#to create role 'airflow'
CREATE DATABASE airflow;
#to create DATABASE
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO airflow;
sudo service postgresql restart #after exiting the shell
```

Then I changed the pg_hba.conf:

```
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all            127.0.0.1/32          md5
#**This was the previous connection**
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Then I used `sudo service postgresql restart`
Then I used `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` and changed the following:

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
listen_addresses = '*'                  # for Airflow connection
# — Connection Settings -
#listen_addresses = ‘localhost’ # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

Then I restarted the postgresql again `sudo service postgresql restart`

Then I ran `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`

I changed the executor in `airflow.cfg` file `executor = CeleryExecutor`

Then I changed the sql_alchemy_conn: `sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://ubuntu@localhost:5432/airflow`

Then I Then I ran `airflow db init`
For initialization

Then I ran the server 'airflow webserver'

This is the detailed stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 101, in wrapper
    check_and_run_migrations()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 768, in check_and_run_migrations
    with _configured_alembic_environment() as env:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 755, in _configured_alembic_environment
    ) as env, settings.engine.connect() as connection:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3315, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 325, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 888, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 491, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 271, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 386, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 685, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 680, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
```

My Role or user is `airflow` not `ubuntu` I basically need to switch that I'm assuming, any help would be highly appreicated!

Comment: "postgresql+psycopg2://ubuntu@localhost:5432/airflow"  You just told it to connect as the role "ubuntu".  So, you need to change that if that is not what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks it worked, then I ran FLASK_APP=airflow.www.app flask fab create-admin to create a login for logging in.